# I got the error ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, imaging

I installed Pillow and I wrote the code
`from PIL import Image`

I got the error message saying

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 from PIL import Image

File c:\users\hello\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:103
     94 MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 4 // 3)
     97 try:
     98     # If the _imaging C module is not present, Pillow will not load.
     99     # Note that other modules should not refer to _imaging directly;
    100     # import Image and use the Image.core variable instead.
    101     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
    102     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
--> 103     from . import _imaging as core
    105     if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
    106         msg = (
    107             "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
    108             f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
    109             f"Pillow version: {__version__}"
    110         )

ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (c:\users\hello\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

my python version is 3.10.9 and my pillow vesion is 9.5.0

Do you know what the problem might be?